# Can an enderman teleport onto leaf blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to create a wither rose farm in the middle of the void using an enderman farm, but it is very important that the endermen cannot teleport anywhere. Therefore, I want to have the bridge towards the farm made of a block that endermen cannot teleport to, and I have an excess of leaf blocks. Can I use them?

Comment: They can’t spawn on them. But yes, they can teleport there.

Comment: @DanBron That's an answer. not a comment

Answer (score -1):

Use water, surround your farm with water as much as you can, endermen fear water. If they see water they teleport away, all you need is a bucket and a river nearby, mine some iron make a bucket and go get some water and dig holes all around your farm and fill it with water. Good Luck ;)

Comment: I know this isn't what you asked but you said it's important to keep endermen out so I wanted to help.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. It also doesn't help the asker, because they want to build a path.

Answer (score -1):

I believe Enderman can teleport to non-waterlogged leaf blocks, though according to the Gamepedia Wiki;

"Endermen never teleport into waterlogged blocks. Exceptions are carpet that is not above a block made of a movement-blocking material, lily pads and snow layers stacked 10 deep or more, as their materials are not flagged as blocking movement even though the blocks themselves do so."

So prehaps water-logged leaves could work with what you want to build.

Comment: Leaves are full blocks, you can't waterlog them.

Comment: @Fabian Röling you should be able to waterlog leaves, as you definitely can on Bedrock Edition at the very least. I don't see why this wouldn't work in Java as well.

Comment: Waterlogging works very differently between the two games. On MCJava there is only "waterlogged with a source" or "not waterlogged" and it only exists for a small number of blocks. This list doesn't even include doors. And especially no full blocks, which I would consider intended behaviour. Anyway, please only answer if you actually know that your answer works in the game that this was asked about. Guesses should be comments, not answers.

Comment: Ah, my apologies I didn't know that waterlogged leaves were a Bedrock exclusive.  Though despite that, any waterlogged block should be able to solve the OP's issue, if they have an excess of leaves, then they would likely have a decent amount of planks stored somewhere and could use waterlogged planks as I know for a fact that those are on both versions.

Comment: I guess you mean waterlogged wooden slabs, yes, those exist.

Comment: Oh dang, I must've of forgotten to say slabs after saying "waterlogged planks". Thank you for catching that typo for me.